Compiling and Linking Py-torch C++ API
Download:
https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-2.2.2%2Bcpu.zip
linked against all .so files in:
libtorch\lib\

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS \n \l
gcc 9.4.0
Python 3.7.1

getting the following errors:
/bin/ld: : undefined reference to `c10::UndefinedTensorImpl::_singleton'

/bin/ld: : undefined reference to `torch::nn::Conv2dImpl::forward(at::Tensor const&)'

/bin/ld: : undefined reference to `c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*)'

what is missing?
